# Google App Engine standard doesn't compress my Next.js/Express app

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, next.js

I'm trying to figure out what to do to make Google App Engine (standard version) apply compression to the output of my Next.js/Node.js/Express application.

As far as I've gathered, the problem is that

1) Google's load balancer removes all meta tags indicating that the client supports compression from the request, and thus `app.use(compression())` in `server.js` won't do anything. I've tried to force compression using a `{filter: shouldCompress}` function, but doesn't seem to matter since Google's front end *still* returns an uncompressed result. (Locally compression works fine.)

2) How and when Google's load balancer chooses to apply compression is a mystery to me. (And particularly, why not to my silly but large `application/javascsript` content :))

Here's what they say in the docs:

> If the client sends HTTP headers with the original request indicating
>   that the client can accept compressed (gzipped) content, App Engine
>   compresses the handler response data automatically and attaches the
>   appropriate response headers. It uses both the Accept-Encoding and
>   User-Agent request headers to determine if the client can reliably
>   receive compressed responses.
>   [How Requests are Handled: Response Compression](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/how-requests-are-handled#response_compression)

So there's that. I'd love to use App Engine for this project but when index.js is 700KB instead of a compressed 200KB, it's kind of a showstopper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Request Headers and Responses documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/reference/request-response-headers#removed_headers) for Node.js, the  Accept-Encoding header is removed from the request for security purpose.

> **Note**: Entity headers (headers relating to the request body) are not sanitized or checked, so applications should not rely on them. In particular, the Content- MD5 request header is sent unmodified to the application, so may not match the MD5 hash of the content. Also, the Content-Encoding request header is not checked by the server, so if the client sends a gzipped request body, it will be sent in compressed form to the application.

Also note the response on [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/WLEJgICkmts/iM5NWOcjCAAJ) which states:

> Today, we are not passing through the `Accept-Encoding` header, so it is not possible for your middleware to decide that it should compress.
>
> We will roll out a fix for this in the new few weeks.

Comment: Ok, cool and good information! Do you have any insight into what server response headers the frontend checks to arrive at the conclusion automatic gzip or not?